# How can I access my webapp from my pc by Android emulator?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tomcat, vraptor

Well I'm trying to access my webapp from my android emulator device an exception is throwing: **java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

In browser all right:

[Browser access from http://192.168.25.7:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwDey.png)

But When I try to access it from my app:

[App code and thrown exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXOhj.png)

How should I make it work?

Note: I'm using **Tomcat 9**, **vraptor** to webapp and **eclipse** to android programming.

Comment: provide us with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use: http://10.0.2.2:8080 instead to access your pc's localhost from the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have config permission to access network in AndroidManifest.xml.For example:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

But you first change your IP like MoQ's suggestion.